# Sign apk using certificate.pem and key.pk8 in Android Studio by using gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

how to use below commands in Android Studio?
java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 file.apk file-signed.apk

Comment: Did you find how to do it? Can you share if you did?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My reply comes probably too late for the question itself, but could be useful to someone else.

In order to sign an apk with Android studio you need to provide a .keystore file.
Now, following [this](http://devarea.com/signing-android-application/#.XI-qdBNKjRZ) tutorial I found [this](https://github.com/getfatday/keytool-importkeypair) tool that allows you to create a keystore file starting from your .pk8 and .pem files.
All you have to do is:

1. Download keytool (from the link I gave you)
2. Generate your keystore file `keytool-importkeypair -k ~/.android/key.keystore -p android -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert platform.x509.pem -alias platform`
3. Use it to sign your app, either clicking on 'Build--> Generate Signed Bundle / APK' or using singingConfig in your app's .gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        storeFile file("key.keystore")
        storePassword 'password'
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'password'
        }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this process going to generate a platform.pk8 key that I can use to make my app be System app rather than regular app?

Comment: @The Good Giant Can you please explain a little bit more? Why it says "keytool-importkeypair is not recognised as an internal or external command.." I have installed keytool.

Comment: @user16388400, you have to use the keytool-importkeypair not regular keytool. The link to that is in the answer.

Comment: This answer works, but if you want to do the same with OpenSSL and Keytool and without using keytool-importkeypair, then just follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58215617/467509

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate unsigned apk
2. Download signapk.jar (I found one here: https://github.com/appium/sign - link to .jar: https://github.com/appium/sign/raw/master/dist/signapk.jar)
3. Place it under your app folder
4. Locate your certificate and key (certificate.pem, key.pk8)
5. Open terminal in Android Studio and type `java -jar signapk.jar <path_to_certificate>/certificate.pem <path_to_key>/key.pk8 <path_to_your_apk>/yourapp-unsigned.apk yourapp-signed.apk`
6. If succeeded, locat your yourapp-signed.apk under your app folder

Comment: how can I do this in UI of android studio in order to do it automatically after each build?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy APK and Key Files to the following folder:
   C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools*
   (Any of the subfolders will do; for example: 27.0.3)
2. Sign the APK with the following command:
   apksigner.bat sign --key .pk8 --cert .x509.pem APKFILE.apk